# google spreadsheet script - how to get the reference to a specific block inside method

Tags: reference, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to fill a block with a int from a method that I wrote with the script editor.

```
        And ofcourse I know I can just left click a block and type the number in, but I need to do more than that.
```

I have no experience in java script, but I code in JAVA, so I could understand a lot of it.

I have the following code inside my method:

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    sheet[5][15] = 60 ; // I have stripe down almost everything to where my  problem occurred`

I am trying to fill row 5, column O with 60. But it isn't working.
I tried sheet[5][O] = 60; but this doesn't work neither.

So how can I refer to the location 5,O on the sheet and give it a value?

Comment: Is this a joke?  It seems you have read the 5 first lines of the documentation, I'd suggest you continue just a little bit more... No offense but one should at least show a minimal knowledge of what this is about and your question denotes the exact opposite.

Comment: hey at least there was code with a failed attempt Serge. trying the col string reference in brackets with the row as number next to a sheet obj is a creative shortcut though. what 5 lines are you referring to anyhow?

Comment: Mmmmh, okay, at least it was creative indeed...:-)  5 rows was a way of speaking a bit sarcastic, sorry about that, I know it is not the best behavior but sometimes I feel kind of irritated when I see such undocumented posts, don't you?   :-)   getting values from a sheet is really a basic thing to know and is well documented in the doc, it has also sooooo many examples around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheet.getRange("O5").setValue(60);`
or
`sheet.getRange(5, 15).setValue(60);`

Comment: thanks, but now i get the error saying i don't have permission to set value? is there a way to give myself permission? all of this is happening at the script level